# what is the percentage chance that I will invoke the spear every 5 strokes?

Tags: probability, percentages

if I have a 3% chance to summon a magic spear every 1 strokes, what is the percentage chance that I will invoke the spear every 5 strokes?

Attemp:
I don't think this is correct; if I'm not mistaken, the question is asking the probability that only one spear is invoked every 5 strokes. Then, the probability would be $\binom{5}{1} \cdot \frac{3}{100} \cdot (\frac{97}{100})^4 = 0.13279...$ so the answer is about $\boxed{\text{13.3 percent}}$.

Comment: The phrasing "every $5$ strokes" suggests that this happens repeatedly (indefinitely?).  If this is the case, then the probability goes to $0$ as time goes on.  Is this the exact wording?  If so, is there a total number of strokes mentioned anywhere?

Comment: 5 strokes is a "sequence". What is the percentage chance that a sequence will invoke a spear? (Consider it to be a limited number)

Comment: You are correct about the probability to get **exactly** one spear (not zero, not two or more) in five strokes. Are you interested to know how likely it is to get **at least** one spear in five strokes? (I would guess it is not a bad thing to get more than one spear.)

Comment: @David K Yes, I want to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of the work of a probability problem like this is translating the question into terms that are more "probabilistic".

If each stroke has a $3\%$ chance to summon a spear,
you can treat the summoning of a spear in one stroke as a Bernoulli variable with $p=0.03$, that is, probability $0.03$ of success.

If you have a sequence of $5$ strokes, and each has an independent chance to summon a spear, the number of spears summoned is a binomial variable $X$ with
$n=5,$ $p=0.03$.

You appear to have correctly intuited this, because the formula
$\binom{5}{1} \cdot \frac{3}{100} \cdot (\frac{97}{100})^4 \approx 0.13279$
is the correct formula for the probability that $X=1$ (you summon exactly one spear)
if $X$ is defined as above.

To summon **at least** one spear, notice that the only way you will **not** summon at least one spear is if you summon no spears at all.
So compute the probability that $X=0$ (no spears).
Then when you subtract that probability from $1,$ what is left will be the probability that $X \neq 0,$ which is the probability that you get at least one spear.

As you probably know, $P(X=0) = (\frac{97}{100})^5$ in this example.